# C# and LINQ: ordering a query by a nested query's value

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm writing a simple forum in ASP.NET that sits on top of an Entity Framework database in C#.

Each `Topic` object has a navigation property `Posts` pointing to a collection of `Post` objects.  Each `Post` object has a property `When` that indicates when the post was made.

`Post.Parent` is type `Topic`.  `Post.Identifier` and `Topic.Identifier` is type `Int32`.  Only `Post` has a `When` property; `Topic` has no such property.  `Topic.Parent` is a third type `Forum` that is referenced by its `Identifier`.

My problem is this: I can't seem to find a way to sort all Topic objects by the *last* post made in each topic.  I've tried this:

```cs
var topics = from t in context.Topics
             from p in a.Posts
             where t.Parent.Identifier == forum.Identifier
             orderby p.When descending
             select t;
```

But I got duplicate `Topic` objects and sorting was *not* by latest post date descending.

I then tried this:

```cs
var topics = (from t in context.Topics
              let lastPost =
                  (from p in context.Posts
                   where p.Parent.Identifier == a.Identifier
                   orderby p.When descending
                   select p).FirstOrDefault().When
              where t.Parent.Identifier == forum.Identifier
              orderby lastPost descending
              select t).Distinct();
```

It eliminated the duplicate problem, but still no sorting.  I even tried [a suggestion from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931617/linq-query-for-a-forum):

```cs
var topics = (from t in context.Topics
              let posts = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Parent.Identifier == t.Identifier)
              let lastPost = posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.When).FirstOrDefault()
              where t.Parent.Identifier == forum.Identifier
              orderby lastPost.When descending
              select t);
```

Not sure what to try next; it seems that these more advanced LINQ expressions escape me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var topics = from t in context.Topics
             where t.Parent.Identifier == forum.Identifier
             let lastPost = t.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.When).First()
             orderby lastPost.When descending
             select t;
```

(assuming a `Topic` has always one or more `Post`)

Comment: Works perfectly!  Just had to change .First() to .FirstOrDefault() since it's not the final call in the query.  Thanks!